# Full text search records not showing up

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a column in my table to which I have added a Full Text Index. When I write a query to do contains on that particular column, the query gives the output of those records which matches with contain and which were added to the table before 3-4 hours and later. Those records which are added recently to the table don't show up in the output even though their text matches with the contains text.

```
Create table Table1 (Id int, Name varchar(20), Message varchar(1000), CreatedAt datetime)
```

Message is the column which has full text index.

Can someone please help me as to why is this behavior of SQL and what can I do to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your full text index isn't being populated after changes to the data. You should either set up **automatic population** of the index or perform **manual population** whenever you update the data.

More here: [MSDN: Populate Full-Text Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx)